# TextMeshPro isn't attach to a GameObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on this Unity project and my code keeps saying that there is not a TextMeshPro attached to an object when there clearly is one.

[image: unity screenshot]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class NumIdentifier : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public GameObject[] codigosItem;
    int[] numCodigos;
    TextMeshPro[] codigosTexto;

    /*public GameObject[] tituloItem;
    string[] titulos;
    TextMeshPro */
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GuardarCodigos();
    }
     
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void GuardarCodigos()
    {
        codigosItem = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Codigo");
        codigosTexto = new TextMeshPro[codigosItem.Length];
        numCodigos = new int[codigosItem.Length];


        for (int i = 0; i < codigosItem.Length; i++)
        {
            // Obtener el componente TextMeshPro del GameObject
            codigosTexto[i] = codigosItem[i].GetComponent<TextMeshPro>(); //ORDEN CODIGOS: PAG10 DELANTE, PAG 1O ATRAS, PAG 9 DELANTE, PAG 9 ATRAS
            if (codigosTexto[i] != null)
            {
                Debug.Log(codigosTexto[i].text);
                int.TryParse(codigosTexto[i].text, out numCodigos[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.LogError("El objeto " + codigosItem[i].name + i + " no tiene un componente TextMeshPro adjunto.");
                // Puedes manejar esto de otra manera según tus necesidades
            }
            //int.TryParse(codigosTexto[i].text, out numCodigos[i]);
            
        }
        System.Array.Reverse(numCodigos); //ORDEN CODIGOS: PAG1 ATRAS, PAG1 DELANTE, PAG2 ATRAS, PAG3 DELANTE

        for(int i = 0;i < numCodigos.Length;i+=2)
        {
            int numReserva = numCodigos[i];
            numCodigos[i] = numCodigos[i + 1];
            numCodigos[i+1] = numReserva;
        } //ORDEN CODIGOS: PAG1 DELANTE, PAG1 DETRAS, PAG2 DELANTE, PAG2 DETRAS
        
    }


}
```

I tried to add something like searching in children but nothing works.

Comment: Hi, please use <TMP_Text> Component if you are using UI TextMeshPro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the type `TextMeshProUGUI`.

> designed to work with the CanvasRenderer and Canvas system. This component is an ideal replacement for the UI.Text component.

The other component, `TextMeshPro` is a replacement for the legacy `TextMesh` component.

> designed to work with the MeshRenderer. This component is an ideal replacement for the legacy TextMesh component.

Replace your array type with `TextMeshProUGUI`, and anywhere you were using the incorrect type.

```
private TextMeshProUGUI[] codigosTexto;
```

and

```
codigosTexto[i] = codigosItem[i].GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
```

Comment: or simply use the base `TMP_Text` so your code could in theory work for both ;)

Comment: @derHugo good point, TMP_Text does work for both the TMP text and TMP text mesh components.